# Hide / Show Multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, css, forms, html

I am trying to create a form that has various hide/reveals in it and one of the last parts I need to do to this form is SHOW the payment information fields when only Credit Card is selected.

I have a test page setup here: http://www.faa.net.au/test/femmes-member-form.html

Process so far is:

1. Enter your details
2. Select Event Date
3. Selecting Member + 1 or more Guests ask for payment details
4. At the moment, I have displayed the 3 DIVs that I want to appear depending on the radio selection made but when I hide these, the code I have in place at present doesn't work.

Can anyone help me here at all please?

If you need the code, please let me know, with a number of different elements involved I didnt want to paste the whole thing on here, hopefully you can see the Source Code?

Here is the Javascript I have at present but not sure if its this that is wrong or if its clashing with something else?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.cat_dropdown').change(function() {
                $('#payMethod').toggle($(this).val() >= 2);
            });
        });     
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".payOptions").click(function () {
                $(".paymentinfo").hide();
                switch ($(this).val()) {
                    case "Credit Card Authorisation":
                        $("#pay0").show("slow");
                        break;
                    case "Direct Deposit":
                        $("#pay1").show("slow");
                        break;
                    case "Cash Payment (FAA Office)":
                        $("#pay2").show("slow");
                        break;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Post your code which doesn't work.

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried so far. This is not a site where you hire developers to do the work for you (as you don't pay anyone). This a community that helps you with code. We don't build complete code for you to use.

Comment: @aBhijit - code added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per viewing code from View Souce and guessing that you have not added correct class  in event handler. thus click event for radio is not getting invoked.

Change

```
$(".payOptions").click(function () {
```

to

```
$(".paymentmethod").click(function () {
```

Comment: Annoying when something so simple like that makes all the difference. That worked perfectly, thanks! Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to look at your code.

Comment: I have applied this update but now that I get the DIVs to appear, whenever I select Credit Card Authorisation and then choose a Card Type, the seems to keep the selection but it actually disappears, same if I choose Number of Tickets first and then choose a date, the payment div disappears. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted any source, but if you are using jQuery, you can simply do:

```
$(".commonclass").hide();
```

Provided that all 3 divs have the "commonclass" class.

Answer (score 0):

Process goes something like this:

- Start clean: hide all payment methods
- Your radio inputs have `paymentmethod` class, so attach a change event listener to those elements
- When one of the radios is selected, hide all of the payment methods, determine the one you want to show using `index`, and show that div

---

```
$('#pay0, #pay1, #pay2').hide();

$('input.paymentmethod').on('change', function(){
  $('#pay0, #pay1, #pay2').hide();
  var selected = $('input.paymentmethod').index($('input.paymentmethod:checked'));
  $('#pay'+selected).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Used to jquery** as like this

**Css**

```
#pay0, #pay1, #pay2{display:none;}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#payment').change(function(){
        if($('#CAT_Custom_255277_0').attr('checked')){
            $('#pay0').show();
            $('#pay1').hide();
            $('#pay2').hide();
        }
        else if($('#CAT_Custom_255277_1').attr('checked')){
            $('#pay1').show();
            $('#pay0').hide();
            $('#pay2').hide();
        }
        else if($('#CAT_Custom_255277_2').attr('checked')){
            $('#pay2').show();
            $('#pay0').hide();
            $('#pay1').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/Mb4Cz/)**

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you're trying like below,

1. select value from `dropdown`, if the `value !== "1"` then show payment radio buttons
2. Based on the `radio` button selection, you want to show the respective div

From viewing your source code, it seems you're using `jQuery` lib and there use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=dropdown]').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val() !== 1)
            {
                $('input[type=radio]').show();
            }
    }

    $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val() === "Credit Card Authorisation") {
            $('#pay1').hide();
            $('#pay2').hide();
            $('#pay0').show();
        }
        else if($(this).val() === "Direct Deposit"){
            $('#pay0').hide();
            $('#pay2').hide();
            $('#pay1').show();
        }
        else if($(this).val() === "Cash Payment (FAA Office)"){
            $('#pay0').hide();
            $('#pay1').hide();
            $('#pay2').show();
        }   
    });
});
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: I have tried replacing the code with what you have above but it still doesn't show the payment details when you click on the radio buttons, am I missing something here or do I need to position the code elsewhere or something?